# How can I able to call FragmentActivity containing viewpager with three tabs from Navigation Drawer Item?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, swipe, navigation-drawer

This is one  of the method() of Navigation Drawer activity...

Code Snippet:

```
/**
   * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 **/

    private void displayView(int position) {

     // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (position) {
       case 0:
          fragment = new ViewFragment();
       break;
       case 1:
          //here i should call the FragmentActivity     
       default:
       break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create intent with fragment activity and use startActivity() to launch the fragment Activity.

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new ViewFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        //here i should call the FragmentActivity
         Intent intent = new Intent(Context, FragmentActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
                 default:
        break;
    }
```

But make sure that your FragmentActivity. In FragmentActivity you have to use fragment to display the content.

Comment: can u post your code here..for me it is working fine.

Comment: @Dasari This is working. But my FragmentActivity is also initializing ActionBar. so when i call FragmentActivity, everything is initialized again. so it gives a lag to closing of NavigationDrawer. I am able to call viewpagr and my fragments correctly, but the problem is this glitch/lag in NavigationDrawer while closing.